# double in C preprocessor directives

Tags: c

What is the differences between,

```c
#define myvariable 1.25
```

and,

```c
#define myvariable (double)1.25
```

while declaring a preprocessor directives in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the preprocessor will, when it sees `myvariable`, substitute in `(double)1.25` rather than `1.25`.

This will have no effect on your code (possibly bizarre edge cases notwithstanding) since `1.25` is *already* a double literal, as per `C11 6.4.4.2 Floating constants /4`:

> An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter `f` or `F`, it has type `float`. If suffixed by the letter `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`.